# Syntax for a cell in vba

Tags: excel, api, vba, syntax, cell

I ma just starting up with VBA and I have come into quite a bit of trouble with the Syntax.  Is the format for a cell in vba, (column, row) or (row,column)?

Is there a conclusive API for VBA similar to the API on the Oracle site for Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming Excel.

There is VBA the language which is one thing, and then there is how the application hosting VBA (Excel, Word etc) exposes itself to VBA (via its *Object Model*) which is what your specific question relates to.

The argument order is:

```
 .Cells(row, column)
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196273(v=office.14).aspx)

See [*References*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fp123562.aspx) for VBA and Excel Object Model documentation by version.